# Flask-JWT doesn't seem to recognize current_app

Tags: python, flask, flask-jwt

I want to use Flask-JWT with my app.  When I try to initialize it with `current_app`, I get an error.  Up to this point I've been using `current_app` successfully in place of `app = Flask(__name__)` so this was a bit unexpected. Is there something I'm missing?

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile("./config.py")

from app import api_auth
app.register_blueprint(api_auth.bp)
```

`api_auth.py`

```
from flask import current_app
from flask_jwt import JWT

def authenticate(username, password):
  ...
  return user

def identity(payload):
  ...
  return userid_table.get(user_id, None)

jwt = JWT(current_app, authenticate, identity)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import app as application
  File "./main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from auth import api_auth
  File "./auth.py", line 59, in <module>
    jwt = JWT(current_app, authenticate, identity)
  File "/opt/mist_base/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_jwt/__init__.py", line 216, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "/opt/mist_base/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_jwt/__init__.py", line 220, in init_app
    app.config.setdefault(k, v)
  File "/opt/mist_base/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/opt/mist_base/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/opt/mist_base/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 51, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

Comment: NOTE for newcomers: use instead, the Flask-JWT-Extended, which is found https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, has been updated more recently and has better documentation.

Answer (score -1):

you need to initialize your class 'current_app' before you can actually use it.

```
current_app = Flask(__name__)
```